# undefined methods form [NEWBE]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

So I have a form and corresponding classes. I got an error:

```
undefined method `start' for #<Klass id: nil, name: nil, teacher: nil, day: nil>
```

for line: `<%= f.text_field :start, class: 'form-control' %>`
and (when I'm trying to delete the above one) `<%= f.text_field :duration, class: 'form-control' %>`

removing both fields makes my website ok.

My whole form code:

```
<%= form_for @klass do | f | %>
    <div class = “form-group”>

        <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :name %>
              <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :teacher %>
              <%= f.text_field :teacher, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :start %>
              <%= f.text_field :start, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :duration %>
              <%= f.text_field :duration, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :day %>
                <%= f.select :day, ['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN'] %>
            </div>

            <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>

    </div>

<% end %>
```

model (changing integer to string doesn't make any difference, but that is the only difference betweenthese two fields and the rest of the form that I can see) :

```
class Klass < ActiveRecord::Base
     validates :name, presence: true
     validates :teacher, presence: true
     validates :day, presence: true
     validates :start, presence: true
     validates :duration, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
end
```

database file:

```
class CreateKlasses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :klasses do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :teacher
      t.string :day
      t.integer :start
      t.integer :duration
    end
  end
end
```

and controller:

```
class KlassesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @klass = Klass.new
    end
end
```

Looks for me like I missed to declare these two form fields but where else I can look for it?

Comment: Have you persisted the migrations on the db? rails db:migrate?

Comment: Yes. Before that I got an error like "migration in progress" or similar. And other fields (name, teacher and day) work fine too.

Comment: Can you see __all__ the attributes within the rails console?, did you restart your server by any chance?

Comment: I restarted the server. And I cannot see them in console as well (these two only,  the rest of attr are fine).

Comment: run `rails db:migrate:status` what do you get? is it everything "up"?

Comment: Looks fine:
database: /home/ubuntu/workspace/db/development.sqlite3

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20171213222507  Create klasses

Comment: Thank you for your time. I need to stop working for today - if you have any suggestions I highly appreciate that and will try them tomorrow. Greets!

Comment: @Malvinka on rails console check `Klass.new` if it has `start` column?

Comment: @Gabbar it doesn't (neither duration). 2.3.4 :001 > Klass.new
 => #<Klass id: nil, name: nil, teacher: nil, day: nil>

Comment: @Malvinka seems you have problem in migration, is it last migration or have you created any other migration after this?

Comment: It's last and the only one. Can I someone "reset" it? I am very new to RoR tbh

Comment: @Malvinka no need to reset, lets try the the solution i'm giving below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- `rake db:rollback`

make sure you have these fields added in migration file

```
class CreateKlasses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :klasses do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :teacher
      t.string :day
      t.integer :start
      t.integer :duration
    end
  end
end
```

2- `rake db:migrate`

now reload rails console

reload!

or just close rails console and open rails console again.

check again `Klass.new` if it has all field that you added in migration. if those field exists then restart server and thats it.

Comment: it works! Thank you for your help! Any idea what mistake could I do?

Comment: @Malvinka i m not sure how did you create the above migration, it might be you have added `start` and `duration` field after running migration, that means if you have run migration that migration will be persisted in db , to write any field in migration doesn't simply appear in model, it need to be persisted , so next time when i did rollback it revert the table and after running migration it added all field including `start` and `duration`.

Comment: I created the whole class at the beginning, without adding any fields... Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Malvinka its ok!, let me know for further guidance, if you stuck anywhere :))